# How to download base64 which is encrypted? and Decrypt after that

Tags: javascript, encryption, cryptography, base64, cryptojs

I want to make image ecrypt and decrypt in client browser.

I have create upload image an encrypt base64. But, i don't know how to download this encrypted image (On format image not text).

after that i want to upload this encrypted image for decrypt.

Thanks for advance, i'm sorry for my bad english.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $("#form-encrypt").on('submit', function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            disabledButton('btn-submit-encrypt');
            let filesSelected = document.getElementById("inputFileToLoad").files;
            let fileExtension = filesSelected[0].name.split('.').pop()
            const password = $('#password').val();
            if (filesSelected.length > 0) {
                let fileToLoad = filesSelected[0];
                let fileReader = new FileReader();
                fileReader.onload = function(fileLoadedEvent) {
                    let base64value = fileLoadedEvent.target.result;
                    let encrypt = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(base64value, password).toString();
            
                };
                fileReader.readAsDataURL(fileToLoad);
            }

        });


        $("#form-decrypt").on('submit', function(e){
            e.preventDefault();

            const ciphertext = document.querySelector('#encrypt-text').value;
            const pass = document.querySelector('#password-decrypt').value;
            try {
                let bytes  = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(ciphertext, pass);  
                const originalText = bytes.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8);
                
                const preview = document.getElementById('preview');
                preview.setAttribute('src', originalText);
                $("#preview").show();
                
            } catch (error) {
                alert('Wrong Password, or Encrypt Text Not Right');
                
            }

        });
    });


    function downloadTxt(filename, data, mimeType) {
        let element = document.createElement('a');
        element.setAttribute('download', filename);
        mimeType = mimeType || 'text/plain';
        element.setAttribute('href', 'data:' + mimeType  +  ';charset=utf-8,' + [enter image description here][1]encodeURIComponent(data));
        element.click(); 
    }

    function disabledButton(elm) {
        const element = document.getElementById(elm);
        element.setAttribute('disabled', true);
        element.innerHTML = 'Loading..';
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yeah, i already know.

I wrong because i encrypt all result in fileReader, you must split a base64 value.

example :

data:image/png;base64,iVBOblablabla

split with ( , ) and you get array
data[0] = data:image/png;base64
data[1] = iVBOblablabla

and you should just encrypt data[1]